# Magento 2 : composer update giving this error

Tags: magento2, magento231, compose-update

I am using magento version 2.3.1

When I have updated composer via command

```
php composer update
```

I get this error

> Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should
> avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
>
> Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid
> using it. No replacement was suggested.

please anyone guide me how to solve this error

currently not working any command, giving same error when run command

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Comment: not yet, can you please guide here

Comment: you can ignore this error and the composer update run successfully

Comment: It comes up a lot during Composer installations. The module still installed, the message is just a false-positive. If it failed, the message would clearly state that.

Comment: I'm seeing this referenced in the following composer files, which suggest they were part of testing. 
vendor\magento\magento2-functional-testing-framework\composer.lock 
and 
vendor\magento\magento2-base\dev\tests\acceptance\composer.lock

Comment: @Chris can you please explain in detail

Comment: The only places your issue 'container-interop' is mentioned is in the two files located in the places I've referenced above. These two location paths have the words 'testing' or 'dev/tests', which suggests its not part of the live site, but maybe legacy testing code. I dont know the answer to this problem though as I'm also having it with about 20 other deprecated packages.

Comment: @Chris Okay i will check and thank you so much for the help. (y)

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error, it's a warning. Informing you that the package `container-interop/container-interop` is abandoned not receiving new updates. It is up to you whether you want to continue using `container-interop/container-interop` or decide to use the package `psr/container` which still receives updates.

When making a decision take account with security and functionality. I wouldn't recommend changing here unless the old packages receives errors due to other packages being updatet.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, that should do the trick

```
composer remove container-interop/container-interop
composer require psr/container
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try and let you know :)

Comment: I tried this but got the following "container-interop/container-interop is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed"

Comment: Do this solution works?

Comment: Clearly it must not work but I can look into it more if you need?